# Titanium and Watchkit Handling JSON in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, titanium, appcelerator, watchkit

I am working with ti.watchkit, and want to send an object from the iPhone to the Apple Watch. I am confused on how I should handle the data. Should the JSON be converted to a dictionary? Most tutorials that I have come across deal with getting JSON from an URL or local file.

I can pass this object as a message:

Titanium

```
Ti.WatchSession.sendMessage({
    message : {
        elapsedTime : et,
        mainTimer : rr,
        segName : rowNames[_index],
        icount : icount
    }
});
```

Swift

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) -> Void {

    let remaining = String(describing: message["mainTimer"]!)
    let elapsedTime = String(describing: message["elapsedTime"]!)
    let icount = String(describing: message["icount"]!)
    let segName = String(describing: message["segName"]!)


    DispatchQueue.main.async {


        if let i = String(elapsedTime) {
            self.elapsedLabel.setText(i)
        }

        if let x = String(remaining) {
            self.intervalTimer.setText(x)
        }

        if let y = String(icount) {
            self.intervalCounter.setText(y)
        }

        if let z = String(segName) {
            self.statusLabel.setText(z)
        }
    }



}
```

I wanted to send an object like the one below. I have tried sending it as is and stringified JSON, and the watch crashed.

Titanium

```
    var workouts = [{
        "name" : "High Intensity",
        "duration" : 20,
        "color" : "green",
        "rest" : 0,
        "number" : "1-1/1-2"
    }, {
        "name" : "Rest",
        "duration" : 10,
        "color" : "red",
        "rest" : 0,
        "isRest" : true,
        "number" : "1-1/1-2"
    }, {
        "name" : "High Intensity",
        "duration" : 20,
        "color" : "green",
        "rest" : 0,
        "number" : "1-2/1-2"
    }];

    Ti.WatchSession.sendMessage({
            message : workouts
    });
```

Swift

```
    private func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message [String  : AnyObject]) -> Void {
    //Not sure how to get the object here and parse it.
    //try JSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(message, options: []) as [Int: [String: AnyObject]]

func jsonToData(json: Any) -> Data? {
    do {
        return try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
    } catch let myJSONError {
        print(myJSONError)
    }
    return nil;
}


    }
```